# out of bound image in iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iPhone development. I am writing code for Crystal Ball App in which the background image is going out of bounds when I run the iPhone simulator.
I am trying to do things pragmatically.
Following is the code

## import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize predictionLabel;
@synthesize predictionArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"crystal_ball copy@2x.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self. view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
    
    
   self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"It is decideley so",
                                @"good things coming", 
                                @"Good time is here",
                                @"Great profit",
                                @"stay possitive",@"Stay Foccused",@"all is well",nil];
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setPredictionLabel:nil];
    [self setPredictionLabel:nil];
    [self setPredictionLabel:nil];
    [self setPredictionLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    
    NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.predictionArray. count);
    
    self.predictionLabel.text = [self.predictionArray objectAtIndex: index];
}
@end
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: maybe you are using a high resolution image (for retina display) but you are running the wrong iphone sim? did you also have crystal_ball copy@.png in the image folder?

Comment: no i did not employ crystal_ballcopy.png in the image folder. Also what kind of image do i need to employ to rectify this. Other point I like to make is that while I use Image View in storyboard the same image works fine - but when i attempt to do the same progamatically the problem crops up

Answer (score 1):

You should create the image without "@2x". iOS handles it already.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"crystal_ball copy.png"];
```

Comment: tried - does not work. Also when i use the same image through storyboard Image view - things work out fine - but if i attempt the same thing progammatically- the error crops up.

Comment: That's because on storyboard, you set the UIImageView's frame, and the image is resized to fit the frame. Programmatically, you aren't setting the frame, so its size will be the image's size. Check the if the image file dimensions are the ones you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Be happy that you ran it on the non-retina simulator. Otherwise you may not have noticed the problem.

This is the issue:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"crystal_ball copy@2x.png"];
```

The retina-thing is a bit difficult to understand when you don't know its history:

Once upon a time there was no retina display. Your file name was just `"crystal_ball copy.png"` in these dark days. Then retina came and Apple tried making it as transparent and easy to the developers as possible. 
If you didn't change anything to your code then the app should still run on a retina device but would not leverage from the resolution. If you provided a file with double resolution and add `"@2x"` to the file name but still didn't change anything to your code then the system will automatically fetch the high-res image on retina devices and the standard-image on non-retina devices.

So provide both resolutions, one with the `"@2x"` and one without, and when referring to the file name omit the `"@2x"`. That's it. This line will fix your issue here:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"crystal_ball copy.png"];
```

Assuming that this image file exists and does have the non-retina resolution.